# How should I best handle a group of table view cells with checkmarks?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

Many apps, including Apple's own Settings app, often allow users to select one of many options by tapping a table view cell that is part of a section.

For example, in the Settings app, when changing the behaviour of double-tapping the home button you choose from "Home", "Search", "Phone favourites", etcetera. When you select one of the options the row gains a checkmark and the label turns blue; the deselected row loses its checkmark and the label turns black.

In order to replicate similar functionality in my app I am doing the following in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

1. Record the index of the selected row
2. Call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` on the table view so that the selected row does not keep its blue background
3. Call `setAccessoryType:` on the selected and deselected cells, passing `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` respectively

This works, but the label for the selected cell remains black. How should I get the colour to change to blue like it does in the Settings app? Is there a way to do this other than changing the label's colour manually? If not, is there a constant that I can use to obtain this colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `textColor` property of cell's label:

```
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Hi Eimantas. The `blueColor` constant is pure blue (#0000ff). Is there a different constant that matches the blue of the checkmark icon?

Comment: Not sure about this. Worst case scenario - you can create own dark blue color. Also - it seems that UILabel has `highlightedTextColor` (together with `highlighted` property). So if you just set your label as highlighted - the text should change automatically to default dark blue color.

Comment: Here's what I'm using: `[selectedCell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:75.0/255.0 blue:133.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];`